# My computer freezes whenever I'm on the internet, why is that?

Tags: windows-7, internet, freeze, firefox

Recently, whenever I'm on the internet, my computer operates normally and then all of a sudden, it'll freeze, and then I'll have to restart it. Some days ago, I had to do that 10 times. Why is this happening? i use windows 7 64 bit, RAM 4 GB, and Mozilla Browser.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information here.

Comment: like Xavierjazz says, more info is needed. Does it happen on certain websites? have you tried other browsers? run your browser in safe mode? Disabled add ons?

Comment: Have you tried the usual diagnostic tests? memtestx86+ or microsoft memory analyser for your ram, smartmontools or gsmartcontrol for your hard disk and so on? What do your temperatures look like?

Comment: Have you tried using different web browsers and see if it is a particular web browser that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that 98 out of 100 cases like this is either GPU or CPU overheating issue. Run some stress tests like FurMark and Prime95 and watch for temperatures. Of course it is better to first check and clean dust from coolers.

Using your computer may cause more damage if it is overheating. Both FurMark and Prime95 can damage your computer if it overheats.

Comment: Also, if it is an older computer dusting it out help with heating issues.  If that is the problem.